# C++ Bars in function parameters

Tags: c++, linux

```
int fd = open(JOYSTICK_NAME, O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK);
```

What does the bar between `O_RDONLY` and `O_NONBLOCK` mean? I've encountered this in OpenGL/GLUT programming and I was curious on the semantics.

Comment: You might want to check out some basic C++ texts.  See here for a list of ones considered to be good by the C++ people on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: Thanks! Will utilize this. How come there are only two books in above intermediate?

Comment: are you for real? I see that you answered some C++ questions, yet you don't know the basic operators? Python, with which you seem more familiar, has the same operator, did it ring the bell? Or is it some kind of a joke?

Comment: I wouldn't consider bitwise operations basic. You honestly expect a student to encounter every semantic nuance in a language? That's why there are questions to be asked.  Why didn't I google? Googling 'bar in between C++ functions' doesn't really cut it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the [bitwise OR operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation).  It takes the individual bits in `O_RDONLY` and combines them with the bits in `O_NONBLOCK`, and returns the combined value.

For example, suppose the binary value for `O_RDONLY` is 11001100 and the binary value for `O_NONBLOCK` is 00001111.  OR-ing these together yields 11001111.

Answer (score 2):

It's the bitwise-or operator. It's used to accumulate bitflags.

Answer (score 2):

It is a [bitwise OR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Bitwise_operators) of the two operands. In this case the operands are both defined in `fcntl.h`:

```
/* File access modes for open() and fcntl().  POSIX Table 6-6. */
#define O_RDONLY           0    /* open(name, O_RDONLY) opens read only */
#define O_WRONLY           1    /* open(name, O_WRONLY) opens write only */
#define O_RDWR             2    /* open(name, O_RDWR) opens read/write */
...
/* File status flags for open() and fcntl().  POSIX Table 6-5. */
#define O_APPEND       02000    /* set append mode */
#define O_NONBLOCK     04000    /* no delay */
```

So `O_RDONLY`:

```
000 000 000 000  (0)
```

is ORed with `O_NONBLOCK`:

```
100 000 000 000  (04000 in octal notation)
```

The result is therefore:

```
100 000 000 000  (0400)
```

Not a very exciting example, but that's what it is doing...

Answer (score 1):

That's the **[bitwise OR operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation)**.

Answer (score 1):

That is a bitwise OR. It takes the binary representation of the two arguments (O_RDONLY and O_NONBLOCK) and applies the OR operation to them, returning the result.